# Shortest distance calculation using GPS Co - ordinates

Tags: geolocation, gps, geometry

I want to know the calculation formula with the help of GPS Coordinates for shortest distance calculation with accuracy >= 5 mtr.

I have checked the Haversine Formula and the Great circle distance formula. But they are good for long distance calculations. If we talk about accuracy in mtrs which formula should be used?

Answer (score 6):

[Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) are accurate up to millimeter scale on the WGS84 approximation of earth's shape (which will be overkill as obviously, earth does not agree with WGS84 to that degree).

A few years ago, I implemented some algorithms for [distance calculation in Javascript](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/geo/distance.html). Feel free to ask if you have any questions about the algorithms as the code lacks comments.

One potential problem is that these algorithms work at sea-level and do not take height differences into account. It might be a better idea to [convert to geocentrical cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system#From_geodetic_to_ECEF) instead and use the straight-line distance instead...

The direct expression for the straight-line distance `d` of points with longitude `φ`, latitude `λ` and height `h` is given by

```
k = √(a²·cos²φ + b²·sin²φ)
r = (a²/k + h)·cosφ
z = (b²/k + h)·sinφ
d = √((z - z')² + r² + r'² - 2·r·r'·cos(λ - λ'))
```

with the following values for the paramteres

```
a = 6378137m
b = (a·297.257223563)/298.257223563
```

Answer (score 2):

If (long0, lat0) is one point and (long1, lat1) the other:

For small distances you can use:

```
x0 = long0 * r_earth * cos(lat0)
y0 = lat0  * r_earth
x1 = long1 * r_earth * cos(lat1)
y1 = lat1  * r_earth
dx = x0 - x1
dy = y0 - y1
d = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

`long` = longitude in radians
`lat` = latitude in radians
`r_earth` = radius of the earth

You can further simplify this formula by factoring out `r_earth` and/or by assuming cos(lat0)==cos(lat1).

Comment: Thanks, I am working with SIM18 GPS Module which is used in Vehicle tracker. for tracking application we need accurate results. Does it fit suitable of tracking application.

Comment: @Prakesh: I don't know what you mean. Do you think it is not accurate enough? You said you don't want to use Great Circle Formula because you have SMALL distances. For small distances this formula will be accurate enough. If it doesn't fit you requirements you have to use Great Circle Formula.

Comment: Thanks so much. i will check & get back to you with results.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Prakash said he is NOT interested in long distances. So I assumed one can neglect that the earth is ellipsoidal, even neglect that the earths surface is not flat over the particular small distance.

Comment: @Curd: He didn't say that at all. All he said was that he wanted decent accuracy. Also, even over a short distance if your value of Earth's radius in that locality is wrong, then your trigonometry will be wrong.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: That's not all he said. He also said  "_But_ they are good for long distance calculations". So I assumed he is interested in something that is good for short distance calculations.